# Couldn't we have a neater election post on meta?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, election

I was checking how was elections on other SE sites and found [this one](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2508/2012-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest). Couldn't we have a neater page there so that all candidates could answer questions and others could follow more easily? I'm lost when I go through the page and see over a thousand comments on every post.

Comment: My understanding is that such threads (and we have them [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2377/7850) at MSE, too) are made after a live chat discussion/debate.

Comment: Well, not exactly like that. The current page is really messy and I don't know where to answer the questions.

Comment: Right. I mean *eventually* we will have something like that! My impression was that the questions (which are in the form of "answers") were to be answered in comments, but those are cluttered. It's easier to identify answers (in comments) when they use numbering (1) (2) etc.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you on that matter.

Comment: That's a big victory for us! :D